# R: Calculate standard deviation for specific time interval

Tags: r, dplyr, standard-deviation

I have a dataset with daily bond returns for some unique RIC codes (in total approx. 200.000 observations).

Now I want to calculate the standard deviation of those returns for the combined period t-30 to t-6 and t+6 to t+30. This means for every observation i,t, I need the 24 returns before t in the window t-30 to t-6 and 24 returns in the window t+6 to t+30 and calculate the standard deviation based on those 48 observations.

Here is a small snippet of my dataset:

```
#My data:
date <- c("2022-05-11", "2022-05-12","2022-05-13","2022-05-16","2022-05-17","2022-05-11", "2022-05-12","2022-05-13","2022-05-16","2022-05-17")
 
ric <- c("AT0000A1D541=", "AT0000A1D541=", "AT0000A1D541=", "AT0000A1D541=", "AT0000A1D541=", "SE247827293=", "SE247827293=", "SE247827293=", "SE247827293=", "SE247827293=")
 
return <- c(0.001009681, 0.003925873, 0.000354606, -0.000472641, -0.002935700, 0.003750854, 0.012317347, -0.001314047, 0.001014453, -0.007234452)
 
df <- data.frame(ric, date, return)
```

I have tried to use the slider package to generate two lists with the returns of the specific time frame. However, I feel that there is some more efficient way to solve this problem. I hope to find some help here.

This is what I tried before:

```
x <- slide(df$return, ~.x, .before=30, .after = -6)
y <- slide(df$return, ~.x, .before=-6, .after = 30)

z <- mapply(c, x, y, SIMPLIFY=TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(z))
{
  df$sd[i] <- sd(z[[i]])
}
```